# VS Code | Whenever pressing 'y' key on the keyboard, command 'python.enableLinting' not found appeared in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I'm trying to press 'y' key then **command 'python.enableLinting' not found** appearing, tried uninstalling/updating vs code and python still seeing the same issue.

VS Code version- 1.68.1
, Python version- 3.7.9

Thanks

Comment: Check keybindings

Comment: @GodWin can you give some more inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably issue with keybindings. You can do the following to remove keybinding.
From `settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > search "python.enableLinting"` if you find that `y` is keybinding for this then `right click>delete` then it will delete the keybinding.

PS: `CTRL+k CTRL+s` will also open your keyboard shortcuts. or from VS CODE CMD `ctrl+shift+p` by typing `help: keyboard shortcut`

Comment: press the gear button in the lower left, or **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts** this will show the key binding